# Jquery Mobile Select check boxes on navbar button click

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am trying to put a checkbox like control in the Navbar which should behave like a toggle.  When I first select the navbar button it should select all the checkboxes below and clicking again will reset the checkbox.

Here is the code I have to display the controls

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul><li><a href='' data-icon="check">All</a></li></ul>
    </div>  
  </div>   
  <div data-role="content" id="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="d">
        <li>
            <div class="checkBoxLeft">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0"/>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="msg">Message 1 </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkBoxLeft">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1"/>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="msg">Message 2 </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JSfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/8dyn9e7s/

How do I select all checkboxes on the click on the button and deselect all checkboxes on an another click.

Regards
Malai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the click event for whatever element, in this case your All checkbutton, and then select all the checkboxes and set the checked property using `.prop()`. Here's an updated fiddle showing the checks toggling on and off. http://jsfiddle.net/8dyn9e7s/1/

Edit: I would suggest giving your link a unique class to listen for, or an id, so it doesn't have to listen to just the ui-click class. Also you may want to handle a case where you don't have any checkboxes otherwise the condition check won't work and it would be better to scope your checkboxes with a class as well so you don't just grab all of them like the example

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this in three lines of jQuery:

```
$("#checkAll").on("click", function(){
    $("input").prop("checked", !$("input").prop("checked"));
});
```

All you need to do is add an id to your toggle button as seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8dyn9e7s/3/

Comment: Nice use of setting the value as the opposite of the current, very concise. i would recommend caching the jQuery lookup though so you don't have to get it twice

Comment: @Lbatson like so?: http://jsfiddle.net/8dyn9e7s/5/

Comment: yep. nice solution. oh, just noticed though, you'll want to put a var in front otherwise that's global but yea that's the drift.

Answer (score 0):

And one more version:

```
$('.ui-navbar .ui-btn').click(function(e) {
    $('#content :checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).toggleClass('ui-btn-active').hasClass('ui-btn-active'));
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Important part here is that you also need to take care of removing active class from the navigation button when in unchecked state.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8dyn9e7s/4/